# Cron job disappering without notice?

Tags: multisite, wp-cron

I have a cron job (doing an sync against an external system) running every 10th minute in a multisite-install. For 2 out of 3 sites it is working perfectly.

On the third site the scheduled job is disappearing without notice?

I've scheduled the cron with [WP Crontrol](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-crontrol/) so there is no of my code adding or removing my crons. It silently just dissappear from the list of jobs.

I was thinking it might be unregistered if the jobs throws a lot of errors but I cant find anything in the error logs except some minor hiccups when the external system fail to respond.

How can I even troubleshoot this?

Comment: if it disappears then your code most likely removes it.

Comment: Yes, but if it did I wouldn't have to ask about it :)

Comment: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/cron-jobs-dissapear-automatically/#post-14299272